# Counting string for each of array elements

Tags: php

I am trying to count strings in each array element.

```
 function pageContent(String $url): \DOMDocument
    {
        $html = cache()->rememberForever($url, function () use ($url) {
            return file_get_contents($url);
        });
        $parser = new \DOMDocument();
        libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

        $parser->loadHTML($html);
        libxml_use_internal_errors(false);

        return $parser;
    }


        $link[] = "https://sumai.tokyu-land.co.jp";
        $url = "https://sumai.tokyu-land.co.jp/osaka";
        $getContent = pageContent($url);
        $getXpath = new \DOMXPath($getContent);
        $getRoute = $getXpath->query("//ul[@class='p-articlelist-content-img']/li[1]/img");
        foreach ($getRoute as $photos){
             $photo[] = $photos->getAttribute('src');
             $link .= $photo;
             $allphoto[] = $link;
        }
```

There is 9 photos in the array: like this `/search/area/image/object_id/K4720000` and I want to add each of element's head to this line `https://sumai.tokyu-land.co.jp`. I tried it, but some **array to string conversation error** popped up.

Any way to resolve that?

Comment: Where does this error `array to string conversion` error occurs? Also your beginning of question `count strings in array` does not make sense and not even related to question

Comment: I already wrote it. "Array to string conversion"

Comment: how did you try to add the heading string? did you try `$link . $photos->getAttribute('src')` instead of `$link[0] . $photos->getAttribute('src')`? ($link is an array), or rather declare `$link` instead of `$link[]` (you don't need an array i guess)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your last bit of code is the problem...

```
foreach ($getRoute as $photos){
     $photo[] = $photos->getAttribute('src');  // This creates photo as an array
     $link .= $photo;  // This then tries to add it as a string
     $allphoto[] = $link;
}
```

instead...

```
foreach ($getRoute as $photos){
     $allphoto[] = $link.$photos->getAttribute('src');
}
```

also change

```
$link[] = "https://sumai.tokyu-land.co.jp";
```

as this is also an array to

```
$link = "https://sumai.tokyu-land.co.jp";
```